# performance difference between while (each) and foreach in Perl

Tags: perl, foreach

The hash that I tested contains around 70000 colleges and each college contains around 20 students.
I tried it 5 times and following are the results. There is considerable difference in foreach performance and while (each) performance. Why is that so?

Code with while loop:

```
while ( my ($college_code, $college_info_hr) = each (%{$college_data_hr}) ) {
    while ( my ($student_num, $student_info_hr) = each (%{$college_info_hr->{'students'}}) ) {
        if($student_num < 104000) { ## Delete the info of students before 2004.
            delete $college_info_hr->{'students'}{$student_num};
        }
    }
}
```

Code with foreach loop:

```
foreach my $college_code (keys %{$college_data_hr}) {
    foreach my $student_num (keys %{$college_data_hr->{$college_code}{'students'}}) {
        if($student_num < 104000) { ## Delete the info of students before 2004.
            delete $college_data_hr->{$college_code}{'students'}{$student_num};
        }
    }
}
```

**When the number of colleges are 70,000 then the execution times are:**

For the code with while loop (Interval time is in seconds):

Interval time: 2.186621

Interval time: 2.058644

Interval time: 2.055645

Interval time: 2.101637

Interval time: 2.124632

For the code with foreach loop: (Interval time is in seconds)

Interval time: 1.341768

Interval time: 1.436751

Interval time: 1.346529

Interval time: 1.302775

Interval time: 1.356765

**When the number of colleges are 248,000 then the execution times are:**

(execution times for while loop)

Interval time: 9.084427

Interval time: 8.438684

Interval time: 9.329338

Interval time: 9.169687

(execution times for foreach loop)

Interval time: 5.502048

Interval time: 6.386692

Interval time: 5.596032

Interval time: 5.620144

Comment: More important than the execution time is how it changes wrt the input size. Time the same code with double and triple input sizes and look at the growth.

Comment: @mob, sorry. That was a mistake. Edited it.

Comment: @perreal.. Sure. Will provide the execution times with in an hour

Comment: Well, for one, the `while`/`each` code is generating way more temporary values than the `foreach` code.  I don't see where `$student_info_hr` is used at all, but the `while`/`each` code still populates it.  Something like `Devel::NYTProf` might help you break down where all the time's going line-by-line.

Comment: Also, I don't know what effect `delete` might have on the iterator generated by `each`.  In the `foreach` loop, `keys` runs once up-front to generate the list of keys.

Comment: @JoeZ: the effect is explicitly defined in the doc for `each`: "Any insertion into the hash may change the order, as will any deletion, with the exception that the most recent key returned by each or keys may be deleted without changing the order."

Comment: @ysth: Would that cause the loop above, then, to iterate more times?  If it reshuffles the keys, then it could be revisiting some keys more than once.

Comment: @JoeZ: no, so long as you are only deleting the most recently iterated key, it guarantees not reshuffling.

Comment: @ysth: Obviously I need sleep, as you did just say that.

Comment: well, you are Joe "Z" :)

Comment: @perreal.. Updated the post with execution times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Perl can't make some optimization which is common in many compiled programming languages. As [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) pointed out, each while cycle you copy data out from hash and you also do many unnecessary hash look-ups. There is some benchmark code you can play around.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:hireswallclock :all);
use Clone qw(clone);

my $data = {
    map +( $_ => { students => { map +( $_ => undef ), 103991 .. 104010 } } ),
    1 .. 70000
};
my $college_data_hr;

sub sum_time {
    my $t = shift;
    $t = timesum( $t, $_ ) for @_;
    return $t;
}

sub my_cmp_these {
    my %bench = @_;
    my %times;
    for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
        push @{ $times{$_} }, do {
            $college_data_hr = clone($data);
            timeit( 1, $bench{$_} );
            }
            for keys %bench;
    }
    $_ = sum_time(@$_) for values %times;
    cmpthese( \%times );
}

my_cmp_these(
    orig_while => sub {
        while ( my ( $college_code, $college_info_hr )
            = each( %{$college_data_hr} ) )
        {
            while ( my ( $student_num, $student_info_hr )
                = each( %{ $college_info_hr->{'students'} } ) )
            {
                if ( $student_num < 104000 )
                {    ## Delete the info of students before 2004.
                    delete $college_info_hr->{'students'}{$student_num};
                }
            }
        }
    },
    new_while => sub {
        while ( my ( undef, $college_info_hr ) = each( %{$college_data_hr} ) )
        {
            my $s = $college_info_hr->{'students'};
            while ( my ( $student_num, undef ) = each(%$s) ) {
                if ( $student_num < 104000 )
                {    ## Delete the info of students before 2004.
                    delete $s->{$student_num};
                }
            }
        }
    },
    orig_foreach => sub {
        foreach my $college_code ( keys %$college_data_hr ) {
            foreach my $student_num (
                keys %{ $college_data_hr->{$college_code}{'students'} } )
            {
                if ( $student_num < 104000 )
                {    ## Delete the info of students before 2004.
                    delete $college_data_hr->{$college_code}{'students'}
                        {$student_num};
                }
            }
        }
    },
    new_foreach => sub {
        foreach my $college_info ( values %$college_data_hr ) {
            my $students = $college_info->{'students'};
            delete @$students{ grep $_ < 104000, keys %$students };
        }
    },
    ikegami_foreach => sub {
        for my $college_code ( keys %$college_data_hr ) {
            my $students = $college_data_hr->{$college_code}{students};
            delete @$students{ grep $_ < 104000, keys %$students };
        }
    },
);
```

Results on mine notebook:

```
                s/iter orig_while new_while orig_foreach ikegami_foreach new_foreach
orig_while        1.56         --      -25%         -31%            -35%        -40%
new_while         1.17        33%        --          -8%            -14%        -21%
orig_foreach      1.08        44%        8%           --             -6%        -14%
ikegami_foreach   1.01        54%       16%           7%              --         -8%
new_foreach      0.927        68%       26%          16%              9%          --
```

Result for `248,000`

```
                s/iter orig_while new_while orig_foreach ikegami_foreach new_foreach
orig_while        6.19         --      -27%         -30%            -33%        -38%
new_while         4.54        36%        --          -5%             -8%        -16%
orig_foreach      4.31        44%        5%           --             -4%        -11%
ikegami_foreach   4.16        49%        9%           4%              --         -8%
new_foreach       3.83        62%       19%          13%              9%          --
```

Answer (score 7):

The `foreach` version only dereferences the `$college_data_hr->{$college_code}{'students'}` hashref once per college, so is faster than the `while` version which needs to do it once per student.

The `foreach` version will likely use more memory though, as it needs to build temporary lists containing the keys for each hash.

[Data::Alias](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias) might help you speed up the `while` solution. I've not benchmarked this, but it should be fairly fast...

```
use Data::Alias;

while ( my ($college_code, $college_info_hr) = each %$college_data_hr ) {
    alias ( my %students = %{$college_info_hr->{'students'}} );
    while ( my ($student_num, $student_info_hr) = each %students ) {
        if ($student_num < 104000) { ## Delete the info of students before 2004.
            delete $students{$student_num};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW inner loop can be rewritten as `delete @students{grep $_ < 104000, keys %students}` So all this code can be as simple `for my $ci (values %$college_data_hr){ my $s = $ci->{students}; delete @$s{grep $_<104000, keys %$s}; }`

Answer (score 2):

Each pass through the `while` loops requires a number of operations (All but the `enter` and `leave` apply to your code.)

```
>perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e"my ($college_code, $college_info_hr) = each (%{$college_data_hr})"
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <#> gv[*college_data_hr] s
5  <1> rv2sv sKM/DREFHV,1
6  <1> rv2hv[t4] lKRM/1
7  <1> each lK/1
8  <0> pushmark sRM*/128
9  <0> padsv[$college_code:2,3] lRM*/LVINTRO
a  <0> padsv[$college_info_hr:2,3] lRM*/LVINTRO
b  <2> aassign[t5] vKS
c  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

Included in there is the copying of the values into `$college_code`, `$college_info_hr`. On the plus side, they're not strings.

Your foreach loop does NONE of that. The only thing that happens every pass is to change what `$college_code` is aliased to. Very quick. The downside, of course, is that it will use more memory.

---

An alternative:

```
for my $college_code (keys %$college_data_hr) {
    my $students = $college_data_hr->{$college_code}{students};
    delete @$students{ grep $_ < 104000, keys %$students };
}
```

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil, Hadn't noticed you mentioned the delete slice too!